# Sorting an XML element's children by node name

Tags: xml, perl, sorting, libxml2

hi i am new to perl and xml trying to sort this XML file by the nodes. i am using LibXML  here is an example of the xml file

```
<root>
        <st_5>val5</st_5>
        <st_1>val1</st_1>
        <st_6>val6</st_6>
        <st_8>val8</st_8>
        <st_4>val4</st_4>
        <st_0>val0</st_0>
</root>
```

here is the code i have so far. some of the code here i got it form some questions posted here on stackoverflow

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;
my @newnodes = qw();
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xmldoc = $parser->parse_file('test2_new.xml');
my($book)  = $xmldoc->findnodes ('/root/.');
$book->appendTextChild('st_2', 'stss');
 $xmldoc->toFile ("test2_new.xml",2);
for my $node ($xmldoc->findnodes('/root/*[text()]'))
 {
  my @nodes =  $node->nodeName();
  push (@newnodes,@nodes);
 }
my @x = sort { substr($a, 3) <=> substr($b, 3)  } @newnodes;
print "soted list \n @x \n","\n";
sub bubble 
{   
unshift @{$_[0]}, $_[1];
for my $i( 0..@{$_[0]}-2 )
 {
  last if $_[0]->[$i] le $_[0]->[$i+1];
  ( $_[0]->[$i],$_[0]->[$i+1] ) = ( $_[0]->[$i+1],$_[0]->[$i] )
 }
}
```

my goal is to sort the list add a new node in the xml file then after it is inserted at the end of the parent list to sort all the nodes in the xml file. so that every after a new node is added it sorts the nodes. i am able to sort the list on print but not in the xml file.

Please help

Comment: Your sorting the *names*. You should be sorting the *nodes* (by their name).

Answer (score 1):

Using [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML):

```
open file.xml ;
xmove &{ sort :k name() /root/* } into /root ;
save :b ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new document and add the sorted nodes to it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $xmldoc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => do {local $/; <DATA>});

my $newdoc = XML::LibXML::Document->new;
my $root = $newdoc->createElement('root');
$newdoc->setDocumentElement($root);

my @nodelist = sort {$a->nodeName cmp $b->nodeName} $xmldoc->findnodes('/root/*');

foreach my $node (@nodelist) {
        my $newnode = $newdoc->importNode($node);
        $newdoc->documentElement->addChild($newnode);
}

#print $xmldoc->toString();
print $newdoc->toString(1);

__DATA__
<root>
        <st_5>val5</st_5>
        <st_1>val1</st_1>
        <st_6>val6</st_6>
        <st_8>val8</st_8>
        <st_4>val4</st_4>
        <st_0>val0</st_0>
</root>
```

Outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <st_0>val0</st_0>
  <st_1>val1</st_1>
  <st_4>val4</st_4>
  <st_5>val5</st_5>
  <st_6>val6</st_6>
  <st_8>val8</st_8>
</root>
```